# Why postInvalidateDelayed(long ms) and MediaPlayer not working in my android phone?

Tags: android, onclick

I am creating an android app and using

```
postInvalidateDelayed(long ms);
```

for delaying for some time and

```
Mediaplayer click=MediaPlayer(this,R.raw.click); // The click file is a click.wav file
```

for playing an audio in onClick

This is working perfectly on android emulator but when i installed the app on my phone 
this doesn't work.No sound is playing and no delaying occurs.

My emulator is working on android kitkat 4.4.2 and my phone have android 2.3.6 and i have deployed my app for android 2.2.3 to 4.4.2.

Please help and if you want code then i will edit it here.

Comment: share your code..and log cat

Answer (score 0):

Example of `postInvalidateDelayed`

```
public DoSomeThingMethod {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int delay=1;
        public void run() {
            // here your delay method
            postInvalidateDelayed(delay);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

example of `MediaPlayer`

```
// song is your song
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

mediaPlayer.start(); // Start Method
mediaPlayer.pause(); // Pasue Method
```